# There is no visible ivar for property named "image"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, uiviewcontroller, ivar

Suppose dummy VC has a private property "image"

dummyVC.h

```
@interface dummyVC : UIViewController
@end
```

dummyVC.m

```
@interface dummyVC ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@end


- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    if(!_image) { // compiler tells me _image is a 'undeclared indentifier'
        //do something
    }
}
```

If I try to use `_image` in its setter, the compiler tells me I am using `undeclared identifier`.

However, if I change the property name to `image1` or `anotherImage`. There is no problem using `_image1` and `_anotherImage`.

Can anybody explain why this happened?

Comment: You're adding a property to the `UIViewController` class itself, in a category? Or you're creating a subclass?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Comment: Can you post a [sample that demonstrates the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell sample added.

Comment: That should work fine. What's your compiler version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that the problem is either

1. You are saying

   ```
   @synthesize image;
   ```

   without telling us about it, or
2. you are supplying a getter method `image` without telling us about it.

When you say do either of those things *and* you supply a setter as you are doing here (`setImage:`), then the synthesized instance variable is named `image`, not `_image`. But if you do *not* supply both a setter and a getter, or you do *not* say `@synthesize`, the synthesized instance variable is named `_image`.

I'm betting that this is the difference between your cases.

Comment: Ah, forgot about I supplied a getter for image after a all-day long programming. Thanks!

Comment: But you learned the wrong lesson. The lesson is, show your code. Your real code.

Comment: Or at least code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I agree with you, I should post the code at first place.